# android render a trail of the user's finger

Tags: android

Looking for some hint how to render a trail of the user's finger.

What I mean is what you can see in Google Keyboard for instance.

[image]

Comment: You can have a look at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTouch/article.html , but it's not as polished as Gabe Sechan answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the Google Keyboard?  They stole that from Swype, lets remember the real inventors.

Override the view's onTouch function (or register as the onTouch listener).  Track the motion events, and store them in a list.  Remember not only to store the current event in a move, but to track the historical events to make the curve smoother.

Here's a blog from Square about how they did it for signature gathering, including example code

http://corner.squareup.com/2012/07/smoother-signatures.html

Comment: I forgot a smilie after that line :)  But being one of the guys who wrote Swype, I like having it remembered even if it isn't as popular as it once was.